# TextViews inside a TableRow disappear when an ad from AdMob is received

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I just started having this weird problem.

Summary of events:

A tableLayout is being populated programmatically. A different tableLayout containing a fixed row in it, on top of this programmatically populated tableLayout, containing headings (4 textViews) for them. It appears perfectly when the activity is loaded.
Besides, A banner ad at the bottom in this activity, and an Interstitial ad request made in onCreate and presented in onPause.

Problem:

As soon as the banner ad displays at the bottom, the 4 heading text views disappear!
As i could not find any means to set a visibilityChangedListener for the textviews, i used different colour backgrounds for the table layout, table row, and the text view, which tells me that the problem is with textviews, though the table row is there (using a touch listener for row, and the colour markings). this does not happen when i'm commenting out the banner ad load statement (interstitial ad still working), not happening when my device is not connected to internet. I've a Nexus4 (JB-4.3) on which this happened, but no issues on emulator (3.2" (GB-2.3.3) included in AVD Manager). Even funnier is that the only place where I am using those text views is to get layoutParams to be set in the dynamic text views created (which appear fine).

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context=".DisplayAmortizationChart"
android:background="@color/layout_background">

<RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adLayout"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:id="@+id/tvHeading"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:background="@color/layout_background"/>

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
                android:baselineAligned="true">

            <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:id="@+id/titleRow"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="true"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/chartHead_serial"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitleSno"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/chartHead_interest"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitleInt"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:gravity="right"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/chartHead_principal"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitlePrin"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:gravity="right"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:text="@string/chartHead_outstanding"
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitleBal"
                        android:layout_weight="11"
                        android:gravity="right"/>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tableChart"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:baselineAligned="true">


        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/adLayout">

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adUnitId="blahblahblah
                           ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                           android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
// output from logcat
        09-19 18:47:55.502    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/EmiCalculatorActivity Debug Logs﹕ AmortizationChart Intent sent
    09-19 18:47:55.522    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/EmiCalculatorActivity Debug Logs﹕ onPause ActivityState written
09-19 18:47:55.602    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/AmortizationChartActivity﹕ TableLayout construction started
09-19 18:47:55.602    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/AmortizationChartActivity﹕ Screen density is high or more: 320
09-19 18:47:55.612    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/AmortizationChartActivity﹕ TableLayout construction finished
09-19 18:47:55.652    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 554K, 6% free 9852K/10448K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
09-19 18:47:55.662    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/AmortizationChartActivity﹕ Banner ad displayed
09-19 18:47:55.662    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/AmortizationChartActivity﹕ Google Analytics started
09-19 18:47:55.672   7804-10166/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head>....</head><body></body></html>
09-19 18:47:55.682   7804-10165/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head>....</head><body></body></html>
09-19 18:47:55.942    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ Received ad url: ....
09-19 18:47:55.942   7804-10166/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ Request scenario: Online server request.
09-19 18:47:56.052    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 561K, 7% free 9802K/10448K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-19 18:47:56.062    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ Received ad url: ....
09-19 18:47:56.062   7804-10165/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ Request scenario: Online server request.
09-19 18:47:57.854    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x760c07f8

//this is almost when the row disappears

09-19 18:47:57.854    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ onReceiveAd()
09-19 18:47:58.145   7804-10172/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 256K, 7% free 9778K/10448K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
09-19 18:47:59.216    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x73f487a8
09-19 18:47:59.216    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator I/Ads﹕ onReceiveAd()
09-19 18:47:59.216    7804-7804/com.swarajk1.easyemicalculator D/Interstitial Status﹕ Interstitial Ad Received
```

Where could be the mistake?

Comment: The problem of disappearing has been **solved**. Out of nowhere, I felt that I do not need a _Relative Layout_ (the one just inside the root Relative Layout) and _changed it to Linear Layout_ instead. I would still like an answer to what could be possible reasons behind this.

Comment: Having exactly same problem. My whole table layout with data being populated programatically get disappear as soon as the adMob bannerAd is loaded.

Comment: Curious to know why does it happen and whats the real solution.

Comment: Also please do post the code where you are creating and adding TextView to the table row programmatically!

Comment: I really wish there was a more official answer than "switch from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout", but that's what worked for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I felt that I do not need a Relative Layout (the one just inside the root Relative Layout) and changed it to Linear Layout instead. This solved the problem.
I suspect that the construction of the layout was encountering some problem after the LinearLayout containing AdView got some content when ad is loaded. This was causing the ScrollView to lose all its space in the RelativeLayout.